# PHP cookie in Wordpress returns null value when logged in

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, cookies

Hi I've got a button click event that uses admin-ajax.php to call up a function in my function.php I set a cookie and try to append an id to the existing cookie value (list of ids).

I'm using admin-ajax.php outside of a plugin very similar to this article https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/

But when I'm logged in as the admin the `$_COOKIE[$name]` always returns `Null`. However when I log out and return as a visitor everything is working correctly. I want this function to work for all users regardless if they are logged in or not. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

**in my Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
        url : myObj.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'store_this_id',
            post_id : post_id
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

**in fuctions.php:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_store_this_id', 'store_this_id' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_store_this_id', 'store_this_id' );

function store_this_id() {
    $name = "mycookie";
    $expire = time() + (60*60*24); // expire in 24 hours
    $value = isset( $_COOKIE[$name] ) ? $_COOKIE[$name] : "test";
    $value .= "," . $_POST['post_id'];

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
        setcookie($name, $value, $expire, '/');
        $_COOKIE[$name] = $value;

        print_r($value);
        echo "\n";
        print_r($_COOKIE[$name]);
    }
    die();
}
```

**Console output [logged out] running two tests:**

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://mywebsite.dev/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
    test,1741
    test,1741
XHR finished loading: POST "http://mywebsite.dev/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
    test,1741,1760
    test,1741,1760
```

**Console output [logged in as admin] running the same two tests:**

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://mywebsite.dev/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
    null,1741
    null,1741
XHR finished loading: POST "http://mywebsite.dev/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
    null,1760
    null,1760
```